# Rspec Double leaking to another example

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am testing a class that makes use of a client that makes external requests and I would like to mock this client, but verify that it gets called, however I am getting a double error.

My test looks like something like this:

```rb
  describe '#execute' do
    let(:attributes) { {foo: 'bar'} }
    let(:client_double) { double('client', create: nil) }
    let(:use_case) { described.class.new }

    before do
      allow(Client::Base).to receive(:new).and_return(client_double)
      use_case.execute(attributes)
    end

    it 'creates something' do
      expect(Something.find_by(foo: 'bar')).not_to be_nil
    end

    it 'calls client' do
      expect(client).to have_received(:create).with('bar')
    end
  end
```

and the first example passes as expected, however rspec keeps breaking in the second example giving me this error:

```
#<Double "foo"> was originally created in one example but has leaked into another example and can no longer be used. rspec-mocks' doubles are designed to only last for one example, and you need to create a new one in each example you wish to use it for.
```

someone knows what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I was using a singleton as a client and haven't realized before, so it was trully class caching it through examples. To fix it all I did was mock the `instantiate` method instead of the `new` method and everything worked.

So in the end this worked:

```rb
allow(Client::Base).to receive(:instantiate).and_return(client_double)
```

Comment: I had to allow :instance instead of :instantiate

Answer (score 3):

### Reusing Fixtures with Let Methods

In this case, `before` is actually `before(:each)`, which is reusing the *client_double* and *attributes* you defined with the #let helper method. The `let` commands make those variables functionally equivalent to instance variables within the scope of the described object, so you aren't really testing freshly-created objects in each example.

Some alternatives include:

1. Refactor to place all your setup into `before(:each)` without the let statements.
2. Make your tests DAMP by doing more setup within each example.
3. Set up new scope for a new #describe, so your test doubles/values aren't being reused.
4. Use your :before, :after, or :around blocks to reset state between tests, if needed.

Since you don't show the actual class or real code under test, it's hard to offer specific insights into the right way to test the object you're trying to test. It's not even clear why you feel you need to test the collaborator object within a unit test, so you might want to give some thought to that as well.

Comment: Thank you Todd for the really good answer, but it turns out it was because the client was a singleton and I haven't noticed yet.. so instead of mocking the :new method I mocked the :instance method and everything worked.